# Append data to a cell in a datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

is there a way to append data to an existing cell of a datatable in asp net C# ?
I have a 4 columns as below that forms a gridview that is being sourced by a datatable - dt.

Data is being sourced by reading a txt file. So at the "Result" column the idea is to validate if the parts exists at a Database, so I made a validation for the ChildPartNumber column and then for the ParentParts column. The thing is that at the validation of ParentParts it overwrites the result that I did at the ChildPartNumber column validation and I am looking to append both results so I can have something like this:
[How the datatable should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpUaz.jpg)

Some of the code:

```
String errorLocation = "Child not found";
dt.Rows[i]["Result"] = errorLocation;

GridView1.DataSource = (DataTable)ViewState["partnumbers"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: dt.Rows[i]["Result"] += errorLocation;

Comment: thanks but I cant vote it as the solution as it was not placed as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the datatable row value, then

```
 dt.Rows[i]["Result"] += errorLocation;
```

If you want to edit the gridview cell value then you can do it in gridview rowdatabound event. ex: http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/120/aspnet-gridview-rowdatabound-example-using-c-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
dt.Rows[i]["Result"] += errorLocation;
```

Hope this helps!